# "Storage" function slows down form submission in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, form-submit

Here is simple submit button which submits form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="action" method="POST">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox 45 (updated from 43 where problem was also present) it takes a long time to submit a form. After inspecting in developer's tools what takes so long I found it's "Storage" function. Here are screenshots presenting the problem:
[image: Storage 1]
[image: Storage 2]

This problem does not occur in other browsers, **so the question is why does "Storage" function take almost 1 sec after form submission, making it look like long submitting** (may it be because a lot of tabs are open) **and how to fix it?** Also why is it invoked? In Firefox Developer Edition this "Storage" function is not present.

Comment: you could try [the profiler addon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler) instead, it should provide complete stack traces. careful though, it's a bit crashy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using [the profiler addon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler) suggested by the8472 I found out it was because of [Lazarus: Form Recovery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/) addon which saves inputs from submitted forms. For interested there is a screenshot:
[image: Lazarus]

After disabling this addon everything works fine, like in other browsers.